# Cocos2d-x 3.0 animation frame by frame

Tags: animation, cocos2d-x

As I know animations are actions. Now I need to play animation frame by frame. Say I have an animation from `N` frames. each frame should be played after `t` delay. Now I want to play animation frame by frame, each frame advance the animation's state. How I can do this?

And what about playing actions frame by frame advancing the state in general.

I ask because I use ECS, and I deal with frames.

P.S. I want to do something like this:

```
Action * a = MoveTo(initialPoint, finalPoint, durationOfAnimation);

a->play(0.001 seconds);
a->play(0.003 seconds);
a->play(0.02 seconds);
a->play(0.67 seconds);
a->play(0.06 seconds);
```

And see the animation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can call a->update(0.001) - see the doc of Action's update : http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/native-cpp/V3.0/db/d61/classcocos2d_1_1_action.html#ac8cae2d59252ed4c924a6c0ec86527db

So instead running the action automatically call the update yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can play an animation and :

```
animation->setDelayPerUnit(T);
```

Comment: This appears to allow you to slow the animation down arbitrarily, but not necessarily to manually play it frame-by-frame?